# Date_format validation Laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to make date_format validation but only for 1 request(who i want to edit). Now when i try to submit i get multiple errors, but i edit only 1 request. How i can do it? This is screen from browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgb7e.png and this is code in controller

```
public function do_event(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'event'=>'unique:XWEB.XWEB_EVENT,event',
        'everyday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'monday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'tuesday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'wednesday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'thursday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'friday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'saturday'=>'date_format:H:i',
        'sunday'=>'date_format:H:i',

    ]);

    $decode = json_decode(file_get_contents(storage_path() . "/app/public/event_config.json"), true);


    foreach ($decode['events']['event_timers'] as $value)
    {
        $name = $request->event;
        $days = $request->days;
        if(in_array(0, $days)){
            $days = 0;
        }
        if($days == 0){
            $time = $request->everyday;
        }
        if(!is_array($days)){
            $config = ['name' => $name, 'days' => $time];
        } else {
            $d = [];
            foreach ($days as $key => $values) {
                if ($values == 1)
                    $d[$values] = $request->monday;
                if ($values == 2)
                    $d[$values] = $request->tuesday;
                if ($values == 3)
                    $d[$values] = $request->wednesday;
                if ($values == 4)
                    $d[$values] = $request->thursday;
                if ($values == 5)
                    $d[$values] = $request->friday;
                if ($values == 6)
                    $d[$values] = $request->saturday;
                if ($values == 7)
                    $d[$values] = $request->sunday;
            }

            $config = ['name' => $name, 'days' => $d];
        }
    }
    $new_config = array_push($decode['events']['event_timers'], $config);
    $newJsonString = json_encode($decode);
    file_put_contents(storage_path() . "/app/public/event_config.json", $newJsonString);
    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('You have added this event successfully!');
}
```

Comment: You should add a `nullable` rule for each rule, or add a more complex check that at least one field is filled in (if it needed for business logic)

Comment: @Aro Thanks! I make it like this `$this->validate($request,[
            'event'=>'unique:XWEB.XWEB_EVENT,event',
            'everyday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'monday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'tuesday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'wednesday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'thursday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'friday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'saturday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',
            'sunday'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable',

        ]); ` and its work!

Comment: But now i have other question, how to validate when i get from POST time - 11:30,12:30. Not just 11:30 for example?

Comment: You mean request time and server time is different?

Comment: @Aro No. Now this work https://i.imgur.com/xD9TtMs.png but i want this to work https://i.imgur.com/klI7ueP.png I want work with 2 times seperated with comma.

Comment: So you need to make a custom validation rule for explode value comma then validate. Or you can send array from frontend, and validate like this `'thursday.*'=>'date_format:H:i|nullable'`